# I have a problem with Moodle where the role of Teacher, nor anyone else, only Manager and admin can edit the course

Tags: admin, moodle

I have several courses set up, in each one I have assigned 2 Teachers and a Manager among the participants. Two weeks ago the Teacher activated the "Editing Mode" tab and everything worked fine. Now it is activated but does not allow editing or uploading resources to the course. No changes have been made from the administration side since we were on vacation. Additionally, when I go to assign a role to another participant from the admin account, sometimes the "Manager" role does not appear but the others do. Now no teacher can edit any course, and no permissions have been changed in the role option. I even tried creating a new role called "Teacher with Editing Permission", inherited from the editor permission archetype, assigned it to a participant, it automatically enables the editing mode option but does not actually allow uploading new resources or editing anything.

I expected the teachers to be able to edit the courses as they did last week.

Comment: I just created a new course, assigned a new participant, assigned the role of Teacher (with editing permission) to that participant. Above, I see the option to enable "editing mode", I enable it, but it shows me as a student and doesn't allow me to make any changes.

Comment: You should be wary that it doesn't seem related to programming.
Putting that aside, have you checked the roles' permissions in your moodle administration ?